# jQuery implementing a simple search box function

Tags: jquery, search

So, I have to create a simple search box. In my right container I have made a search box like this:

```
<div id="searchContainer" class="cf sb">
    <div class="right magnifier"></div>
    <input class="right" type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="search"/>
</div>
```

In the main container I have multiple objects of the class newsItem.

```
<div class="newsItem cf sb br">
    <div class="closeButton right"></div>
    <div class="titles left">
        <div class="Title"><h3>{{Title}}</h3></div>
        <div class="Subtitle"><h5>{{Subtitle}}</h5></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="imageContainer"><img src={{URI}} alt="" /></div>
    <div class="newsText"><p>{{Text}}</p></div>
</div>
```

Now, the search box, after entering some text in it and clicking the magnifier icon,  should search the titles and the content of every object in the main container and remove those objects that don't have the searched text in them. If the search box is empty when clicking the magnifier, all the objects that have been removed should reappear.
I have tried with the following jQuery function:

```
$("#searchContainer").on("click", "#searchContainer .magnifier", function()
{
    var text=$("#searchBox").val();
    var string=$(".newsItem .Title").text();
    var string2=$(".newsItem .newsText").text();
    var m=string2.search(text);

    if(text === "")
    {
        $(".newsItem").fadeIn();
    }
    else if(text.length !== string.length || string.indexOf(text) !== 0)
    {
        if(m<0)
        {
            $(".newsItem").fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```

but nothing happens after clicking the magnifier. I'm probably using the wrong selectors since I'm a complete beginner. Any help to make it work would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle example with your code?

Comment: @Yoshi Sorry, my mistake. All the years I thought it is. Taking it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename the string variable (that's reserved, of course).

Then, you have `$("#searchContainer").on("click", "#searchContainer .magnifier"...`

Try `$("#searchContainer").on("click", ".magnifier"...`

The on method's second argument is a selector to filter descendants of the prime target. I don't that `#searchContainer .magnifier` will match any child... Since the target is #searchContainer

```
$("#searchContainer").on("click", ".magnifier", function()
{
    var text=$("#searchBox").val();
    $('.newsItem').each(function(){
        var $item = $(this);
        var searchtext = $('.Title', this).text() + " " + $('.newsText', this).text()
        var match = searchtext.search(text);
        if(match > -1 || text == ""){
            $item.fadeIn();
        } else {
            $item.fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```

By the way, search feature is usually achieved in pure html, with a form and a backend.

Your search input should be part of a form and the actual search should be done either on the server or with javascript, on form submission. This way, pressing enter in the field would also trigger the callback function (if you put a submit button in there of course).

Pure JS design of such a feature leads to a wrong understanding of "how it all works".

Comment: ok, changed the string variables name and removed #searchContainer from on, but still nothing. I'm working on c9.io, so here's the link of the html https://c9.io/simonbiffy/pzi/workspace/domaci/domaci3/index.html. I'm thinking that I'm not selecting items properly. Take note that the search box is in a different container than the objects I'm searching for the entered text.

Comment: In your online code, you put $("#itemContainer") instead of $("#searchContainer") ?? main.js line 99

Comment: Fix it? Accept answer?

Comment: yes, I changed it but still no change. The blinking line dissapears after clicking the magnifier so I guess it is registering, but it still does nothing.

Comment: Edited answer with theoretically working code. You need to loop on the news items or your search will toggle every item's visibility...

Comment: By the way, accepting my answer will grow your reputation by 2 ;-) and make my time worth... more than nothing!

Comment: Looks like it still needs a little tweaking. If I enter a word that only one object contains, all the objects stay there, but if I enter a word that isn't in any of them, they all disappear. If I click the magnifier while it's blank, they all appear so that part works. UPDATE: scratch that. Entering a word doesn't really seem to work, but if I enter 3 dots (...) they disappear, so I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: Edited answer. (match > -1 || text == "") instead of (match || text == "") line 108 in main.js